# What the shortcoming\problems for narrowOop for the class oopDesc in the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

We that we can use the compressed oops (-XX:+UseCompressedOops) in 64 bit system  , however compressed oops just can address the arrange from 0- 4G as it is 32 bit wide, so what's happens if the total size of all of the klasses space over 4G? Exception happens?

```
class oopDesc {
  friend class VMStructs;
 private:
  volatile markOop  _mark;
  union _metadata {
    Klass*      _klass;
    narrowKlass _compressed_klass;
  }  ;
```

Comment: Could you review your question, you left some words out, and your phrasing is a bit unclear.

Comment: Compressed oops allow up to 32 GB not 4 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should distinguish compressed pointers to java objects (which are enabled by `UseCompressedOops` option) and compressed pointers to `klass` structure (which is VM-private structure, is stored outside of the heap and controlled by `UseCompressedClassPointers` flag).

Answering original question, there is corresponding check on JVM startup in [arguments.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/c22bf83dad09/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1769), so if compressed `klass` space can't be fully addressed by compressed pointers this option will be disabled.

Also note (from question it looks like you slightly misunderstand it), even though you can address only 4 GB with 32-bit pointers, in JVM all objects (and [klasses](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/c22bf83dad09/src/share/vm/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp#l438)) are aligned on 8 (or more, if flag `ObjectAlignmentInBytes` is set), so you can address 32 GB (actually, `4 * logBase2(ObjectAlignmentInBytes)`) of heap objects.

Alignment means that 3 lowest bits of any pointer to object/klass are zeroes, thus JVM can 'compress' them away (that's why they are named such) and add them when needed.
On every object access JVM will transform 32-bit pointer by shifting it and storing into 64-bit register and only then read from memory (optionally adding pointer to heap start).

So, in pseudo-code JVM will replace 64-bit reads:

```
Object read(int64 pointer) {
  return (Object) pointer;
}
```

with this:

```
Object read(int32 pointer) {
  int64 ptr = (int64) pointer;
  return (Object) (heapBase + ptr << 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> however compressed oops just can address the arrange from 0- 4G as it is 32 bit wide

That's not correct since compressed oops can use pointer compression by exploiting object alignment

> so what's happens if the total size of all of the klasses space over 4G?

compressed oops only refer to object pointers, i.e. pointers into the java object heap. The JVM's internal representation of classes (not to be confused with java `Class` objects) does not sit in the object heap. They may or may not use their own compressed pointer scheme, controlled with the separate `UseCompressedClassPointers` option.

If compressed class pointers are used and the compressed class space is exhausted and no space can be reclaimed with a last-ditch Full GC, then yes an OOME will occur.

Comment: So it means compressed oops can address over 4G ? Also can you kindly give me more detail explanation for what's the meaning "compressed oops can use pointer compression by exploiting object alignment"?  Any example is welcomed.

Comment: it's in the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html there also are several other SO questions covering those topics. please do your research. a simple google search turns up several resources [setting google to show english results may help if that's not your native language]. You have not even clarified whether your question refers to klass or ordinary object pointers.

Answer (score 0):

**Compressed OOPS** and **Compressed class pointers** are two related techniques which are used to reduce the sizes of reference variables in 64-bit JVM. The first one is used to reduce the sizes of **user-defined reference variables** while the second one is used to reduce the sizes of **JVM-defined reference** **variables** called klass fields(class pointer) in 64-bit JVM.

If you decide to use ObjectAlignmentInBytes VM flag to use 16 byte or higher memory alignment in order to use more than 32GB with Compressed OOPS feature still enabled, then you should also consider about its side effect of wasting more memory with padding.

You can read [Java Performance Optimization: Compressed OOPS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MT75FSC) book to know more about Compressed OOPS feature. This is the best book to get all yours doubts clarified about Compressed OOPS and compressed class pointers.